# Unable to Upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 From Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 18.04, 17.10, python3, do-release-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade my Ubuntu release from 17.10 to 18.04 without success.

`do-release-upgrade` is returning the following error:

```
Checking package manager

Can not upgrade 

Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' 
symlink.
```

I removed all my `update-alternatives` configuration for `python`, then I tried to reinstall `python3` but it didn't work.

I tried also to completely remove `python3` and then install it again without fixing the issue.

Just for your information `/usr/bin/python3` symlink seems to work fine:

```
neoben@neoben-samsung:~$ /usr/bin/python3
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  3 2017, 21:45:48) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Do you have any suggestion to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Debug it with `strace`: `strace -f do-release-upgrade`. Look at what files/dirs it's trying to open or launch to come to the conclusion that the python is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Following [Velkan](https://askubuntu.com/users/391744/velkan) suggestion, I performed `strace -f do-release-upgrade` finding an issue related to language-pack so I fixed it:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall language-pack-en-base
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Then, reading `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log`, I discovered that there was an issue with Python 2 despite the error log was pointing to Python 3, so I tried:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Now, it seems that `sudo do-release-upgrade` is working fine!